# How to display information in a JComboBox, but choose different information for backend operation

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a list of codes, that correlate to different operations.
I would like to display easy-to-read information for the user to choose from, but when the user makes the choice of what they want, when they click a button, to submit, that the backend operation correlates to the list of codes.
Example:

```
 Displayed          | Backend                        
--------------------|------------------------------------------
 Hardware Inventory | "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}" 
 Software Inventory | "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002}"
```

Comment: Can you add the minimal example?

Comment: So, what I'm doing is wanting to run wmic from a console, but in a GUI format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer depends on whether those label-code pairs change a lot or not. For flexibility:

```
public class FooOperation {
    private final String label;
    private final String internalCode;
    public FooOperation(String label, String internalCode) {
        this.label = label;
        this.internalCode = internalCode;
    }
    public String toString() { return label; } // human-readable, displayed in CB
    public String getCode() { return internalCode; } // ugly but true
}
```

Then, you can load them from a file at application start, and given a `FooOperation[]` that you have somehow loaded, you can display it via

```
JComboBox options = new JComboBox(availableOperations);
```

Options will be displayed according to their `toString()`, but once selected, you can easily determine their internal code:

```
FooOption[] selected = options.getSelectedItems();
if (selected.length == 1) {
   System.err.println("you have selected " + selected[0].getCode());
}
```

If you do not need the flexibility of loading them from a file or classpath resource at startup, you can also go for an `enum` (just use `public enum FooOperation` and initialize all possible operations in the enum class). This is simpler (no files), but harder to extend (you will have to touch code & recompile to change available options)

Comment: Yeah. I don't need the flexibility. They'll be static, and won't ever change.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own class with the not-so-presentable values values and the easy-to-read values returned in the toString()-method. Then add you values to the combo box.
Retrieve the values with getSelectedItem().